# returning distance in soql select

Tags: soql, geolocation, google-map

Has anyone found a way to use the DISTANCE function in a SELECT phrase.  I've seen how to use it in the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses, but what I'm trying to do is something like...

```
SELECT id, name, location, DISTANCE(location, GEOLOCATION(lat, lon), 'mi') 
FROM CONTACT;
```

Why?  I want to show the distance to users in the UI, rather than just sorting by distance.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Supported in Spring 16' release http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37046/can-geolocation-fields-be-used-to-calculate-and-display-distance

Comment: Supported in Spring 16' release http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37046/can-geolocation-fields-be-used-to-calculate-and-display-distance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to the documentation, you can't do that:

> Location-based queries are supported in SOQL in Apex and in the SOAP and REST APIs with the following limitations:
>
> DISTANCE and GEOLOCATION are supported in WHERE and ORDER BY clauses in SOQL, but not in GROUP BY or SELECT.

Referenced from [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm)

You can then go through the list and calculate distance using the Haversine formula, as shown in [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37046/can-geolocation-fields-be-used-to-calculate-and-display-distance) answer by Daniel Ballinger.

If you don't mind a few queries, you could perform several queries to get "Bands" of distance away - 1mile, 5 miles, 10 miles etc by adding

```
DISTANCE () < 2
```

And then

```
DISTANCE () < 6 AND DISTANCE () > 1 ///etc
```

Comment: Thank you!  The limitation from SELECT is exactly what I'm trying to work around.  I really like your suggestion of the Haversine formula and that would probably be good enough despite being "as the crow flies".  Then again, I wouldn't be surprised if the DISTANCE function is taking a crow flies approach anyway.

Comment: Yes, it probably is using a Haversine type approach, although I'm definitely guessing at this point :)

Comment: lame... it even allows you to put it in the select clause without throwing error.  Hopefully they will add support for this sometime in the future...