# How to determine a Geolocation is within a buffer distance from another Geolocation using apex without using SOQL?

Tags: apex, geolocation

I have two location fields of type Geolocation named point1 and point2. I have one radius field . i need to determine whether point2 is located within radius distance from point1 or not. How can this be determined using apex without using SOQL ?

Comment: Check this question and answer out: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32585/what-formulae-does-the-geolocation-distance-use/34285#34285

Comment: this link solved my problem : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37046/can-geolocation-fields-be-used-to-calculate-and-display-distance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this solved my problem :

```
Location loc1 = Location.newInstance(28.635308,77.22496);
Location loc2 = Location.newInstance(37.7749295,-122.4194155);
Double dist = Location.getDistance(loc1, loc2, 'mi');
Double dist2 = loc1.getDistance(loc2, 'mi');
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: it seems there is a `Location` class in apex that does this already. You should use it instead of rolling your own!

The [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) is what seems to be the generally accepted way to do this. It's not native to apex that I can tell. It's been [implemented in java before and seems portable to apex with a bit of work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12600225/740787).

There's no `Math.toRadians` in apex, but I believe you can implement this as

```
private static toRadians(double degree){
    return degree * (Math.PI/180.0);
}
```